# Mysql workbench bad sql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Mysql workbench (5.2.31 to 5.2.34) synchronization feature produces bad sql that fails to execute on mysql 5.1.53...

Error include syntax errors like: double(11) that should be either double or double(11,2)
It also includes other errors like dropping indexes that do not exist and stuff like that...

What am I doing wrong? Are these bugs? Am I missing something? I didn't used to face any problems before...

Comment: Most likely, you aren't doing anything wrong. I particularly find the synchronization feature so buggy that it's hardly usable.

Comment: It didn't used to be buggy... I used to use it successfully for about a year...  suddenly, I am hitting in errors all the time...

Comment: It has been claimed to be resolved in 5.2.38

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and trying for a couple of month, I was not doing anything wrong... It was just a buggy release... My impression in more recent releases is that things are getting better... and bugs are getting fixed and I have been able to use the feature again successfully without hitting in bugs... I hope things continue this way...